# PHP - Check for escaped characters

Tags: php, mysql, sql, security

For a MySQL DB Query I want to check and record for non escaped characters.

As I want to a secure database and want to record attemps (for now) at SQL-injections.

Since it will be in testing this will have to record values to plain text.

As I am unsure about how to go about it. would it be good to use serialize and serialize to see if it brakes as it has issues with escaping characters, proceeded by recording the string.

I realise this is a reactive situation rather then proactive but its still good for testing.

Comment: There is a built-in function for it; `*escape_string`

Comment: How will you distinguish SQL injection attempts from strings which would accidentally cause syntax errors if not escaped?

Comment: Why does the fact that there are unescaped characters represent an explicit attempt at SQL injection? What if someone's name is "O'Rourke"? Or consider even how many unescaped characters are right here in my comment. A good way to prepare your statements, is to use prepared statements :) http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php -- But I don't see the value in attempting to log how often an apostrophe is part of an input string.

Comment: @Allendar i need it to check not for it to add them in as its not recommended.

Comment: how do i check for strings that need to be escaped?

Comment: You use a prepared statement. This is a solved problem that has been abstracted away in libraries: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php . You do not need to code for this problem explicitly.

Comment: thanks for the quick all i believe that vcardillo has the best input. as i have limited knowledge on code i am mindful of certain harmful events that may happen to a website

Comment: You should log the inputs received through web then a column with escaped string of those inputs, their you can flag that what is right for your queries and what can go wrong. It for testing and statistics purpose only

Comment: @justnajm yes it is rather debugging tools are handy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how do i check for strings that need to be escaped?

To directly answer this question: The easiest way is probably to run it through the appropriate escaping function and see whether it changed. E.g.:

```
if ($string !== mydatabaseadapters_escape_string($string)) {
    // there was something escape-worthy in the string
}
```

This does not mean in the least that this string was an attempted SQL injection attack though. Escaping just preserves the SQL syntax by escaping special characters used in SQL statements; SQL injection is only a side effect made possible when you forget to do this. Lots of regular values require to be escaped to not break the SQL syntax without having anything to do with injection attempts.

Comment: I do realise that most mysql syntax may even be my own code. but i do like to have some tools to pick up something that i may not of seen aswell. thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 4):

As others will mention, best practice is to use prepared statements, query bindings, or at a minimum, escaping of your MySQL queries, to secure your database. In short, the idea is that you let an established function/library handling the job of safeguarding your database, rather than trying to roll your own solution. This has the added benefit that you don't need to approve any "questionable" entries by hand, which while possibly good for an educational lesson, is simply not practical for use in a site of any scale.

Answer (score 3):

If you really just want to know if a string needs to be escaped, you could do a test like this (using PDO here)

```
$originalString = 'Some value';
$quoted = substr($pdo->quote($originalString), 1, -1);
// PDO::quote() wraps the string in quotes so using substr to remove them

if ($originalString != $quoted) {
    // log this string as requiring escaping
}
```